# Import css library with webpack

Tags: css, webpack

I'm building a project with Vue.js and I'm using the webpack template to start.
In the documentation [http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/pre-processors.html] I can read this:

> Standalone CSS Files
>
> To ensure consistent extraction and processing, it is recommended to
>   import global, standalone style files from your root App.vue
>   component, for example:
>
> ```
> <!-- App.vue -->
> <style src="./styles/global.less" lang="less"></style>
> ```
>
> Note you should probably only do this for the styles written by
>   yourself for your application. For existing libraries e.g. Bootstrap
>   or Semantic UI, you can place them inside /static and reference them
>   directly in index.html. This avoids extra build time and also is
>   better for browser caching.

So the workflow to include a css library (like Normalize or Bootstrap) is to install it through npm/yarn, copy it to /static and then refer to it in the index.html file?
Because I find this method very tedious and fragile, what if I want to upgrade the package? I will need to copy them again in the /static folder...

There is no other way to include css library installed through package manager with webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) plugin for Webpack. Simply edit your webpack.config.js and import css by doing this:

import css from 'file.css';